# iPhone's iAd doesn't show in Asia country, how to monetize

Tags: iphone, iad

sorry for the silly question but I can't find any answers online.

How to monetize my iPhone App in Asia countries? My App is in Chinese, it's free, and there are thousands of people who've downloaded it and used it. 
Currently I'm using iAd, but the impression in Asia is zero!! Even though there're about 10000 request from there, and therefore my revenue is zero...

(I'm in USA and when I run my app, I can see the iAd showing.)

Does anyone know an Ad network where I can join to monetize my App in Asia countries?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

iAds only work in USA, UK, France, Germany and Japan at this time.

(Not 100% sure about DE and JP, but they are planned to work in early 2011 if they aren't currently!)

Answer (score 0):

[Adwirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/) looks promising

Comment: Thanks, @Ben, I've signed up for AdWhirl, the newer version is under review. But AdWhirl looks like an US based company, do you know which Ad Network should i sign up? There're lots choices like AdMob, inMobi, GreyStripe....etc. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For Users That are looking at this post for July 17, 2014 and greater the current supported iAd country list is: 
(Australia, Canada, France, Germany, Hong Kong, Ireland, Italy, Japan, Mexico, New Zealand, Spain, Taiwan, the United Kingdom, and the United States).

Answer (score -1):

iAds work now in US, UK, France, Germany, Italy

Comment: Those countries are not in Asia!